# Append Timestamp to Ajax URL GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, caching

I am trying to append a timestamp to my URL which is called by AJAX every 5 seconds. I am doing this to stop caching in Internet Explorer browsers. However the AJAX call appears to be not calling now but there are no errors....

This code works

```
<script>
  function loaddoc()
  {
   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     document.getElementById("trainblock").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    } 
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","networkgettrainsleicester.php",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }
 </script>
```

With the extra code to append the timestamp does not work

```
 <script>
  function loaddoc()
  {
   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     document.getElementById("trainblock").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    } 
   }
   d=new Date();
   xmlhttp.open("GET","networkgettrainsleicester.php+'?'+d.getTime()",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }
 </script>
```

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: because that is not appending a timestamp. Wrong quotes... `("GET","networkgettrainsleicester.php?" + d.getTime(), true)`

Comment: Tried this but IE still not updating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You not appending the time-stamp. You are including it as a string

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","networkgettrainsleicester.php+'?'+d.getTime()",true);
```

Change to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","networkgettrainsleicester.php?t=" + d.getTime(),true);
```